# Attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

How do you hook up a textbox to a method in MVC5 using attribute routing, with areas?

This is view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{                                   
    @Html.TextBox("searchpara")
    @Html.ActionLink("Search", "SearchMethod", "Home", new { area = "Timetables" }, null)                                   
}
```

Controller:

```
[RouteArea("Timetables")]
[RoutePrefix("Home")]   
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

Method:

```
[Route("SearchMethod/{searchpara=Test}")]
public ActionResult SearchMethod(string searchpara) 
{
```

It doesn't work. The problem may not be routing?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `RouteArea`?

Comment: David, thanks for response. Removing [RouteArea("Timetables")] gives 404

Comment: Try Jeremy Cook's answer below. I think that's gonna be the ticket.

Comment: You're just giving your textbox a string, how does it know to get that from the route parameter `searchpara`. You probaby want this code inside your textbox. `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["searchpara"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want a submit button, and not an action link and you may need to update the form to post to a specific action if it is not the current action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMethod", "Home", new { area = "Timetables" }))
{                                   
    @Html.TextBox("searchpara")
    <button type="submit">Search</button>                                   
}
```